# macOS Terminal always showing following error on startup "Error: unknown or unsupported macOS version: :mountain_lion"

Tags: macos, terminal

Whenever, I am opening my mac terminal it is showing me the following error :

```
Error: unknown or unsupported macOS version: :mountain_lion.
```

**I do not have any type of mongodb setup as most of the resources I found online was referring to this error when they were trying to work with mongodb.**

I am running macOS Catalina, version 10.15.7. Any suggestion how to resolve or investigate this? If I look in .profile, .bashrc or bash_profile , what should I be looking for?

Comment: I am seeing the same error, there is no mention of mountain lion or an operating system version in my .bash_profile and my .profile.